# Linux Sendmail Same username multiple domains

Tags: linux, email, domain, sendmail

I have configure my sendmail for multiple domains by creating username like

```
sales@domain1.com
sales@domain2.com
sales@domain3.com
```

in passwd file

Now I added entry in file /etc/mail/virtusetable like

```
sales@domain1.com   sales\@domain1.com #escape to count as user not email
sales@domain2.com   sales\@domain2.com
sales@domain3.com   sales\@domain3.com
```

So when configuring the email client you provide your username as
sales@domain1.com,sales@domain2.com etc.
I tested with webmail and outlook it works.

Is this the best way to do it ?.Do i need to put the entry in any other file like genericstable.

Comment: From the description that you are giving it is not clear if this setup is working for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Best way? Probably not.

Though it may work, it is to have a user@hostname in your passwd file.  The better way to do it would be to have a sales1, sales2 and sales3 users in your passwd file.  Use the name field if you want to identify a full email address in the password file.

The virtuser table would then look like
sales@domain1.com   sales1
sales@domain2.com   sales2
sales@domain3.com   sales3

If you have sendmail configured to receive mail at domain1 domain2 and doman3, it should work fine.